# Using another variable for array index limit in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

Instead of limiting my arrays index one by one...

```
int limit=10, data_1[10], data_2[10], data_3[10];
```

Is it possible to use the value of `limit` to limit the indeces of these datas? My code gets an error *"Constant Expression Required"* when I use `data_1[limit]`

Any solutions to use another variable to limit these arrays' indeces in C++?

Comment: forgive me for tagging C, I have just known that the answer I'm looking for, is in C++ basis, Thanks for correction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
const int limit = 10;
int data_1[limit], data_2[limit], data_3[limit];
```

`limit` must be a const

EDIT:
As other answers have mentioned, limit could also simply be defined through a preprocessing step, like so:

```
#define LIMIT 10 // Usually preprocessor-defined variables are in all caps
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you that you must have a constant expression to allocate memory on the stack. For allocating on the stack you have two options (for getting a constant); you could use

```
#define LIMIT 10
```

or you could use `const int` like this

```
const int LIMIT = 10;
```

and with either, this would then work

```
 int data_1[LIMIT], data_2[LIMIT], data_3[LIMIT];
```

You might also allocate on the heap (using `malloc()`), but then you must also call `free()`.

```
 int *data = (int *) malloc(limit * sizeof(int)); /* as an example */
 /* Do something, check that malloc succeeded */
 free(data); /* free the memory */
```

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this with both C and C++, but the right way to handle this is different between the two.

In C, assuming a reasonably up-to-date (C99 or newer) compiler, the way you've done things is allowed, as long as `data_1`, `data_2` and `data_3` are local to some function. They almost certainly shouldn't be globals, so for C the obvious cure is to simply make them local to the function that needs them (and if other functions need them, pass them as parameters).

In C++, you've gotten some answers that cure the immediate problem, such as const-qualifying `limit` and allocating the other three items dynamically. At least in my opinion, these are inferior choices though. In most cases, you should use `std::vector` instead of arrays, in which case you don't need to const-qualify limit for things to be just fine:

```
int limit = 10;
std::vector<int> data_1(limit), data_2(limit), data_3(limit);
```

Comment: Sorry for tagging it to both, your right but this is a simpler stuff to make use of vector..

Answer (score 1):

use a macro or const

```
#define LIMIT 10
```

or

```
const int LIMIT = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

for C and C++

```
#define LIMIT 10
int data[LIMIT];
```

**just** for just C++

```
const int LIMIT = 10;
int data[LIMIT];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the number of answers that propose to use a `#define`, and as the Q is tagged `C++`, I think it should be mentioned, though, that using a `#define` has drawbacks, especially the fact that the compiler doesn't know what `LIMIT` is, as every occurences are removed during the preprocessing stage and replaced with the value. Thus, when debugging, you could get an error message referring to the value (i.e. `10` in this case) but no mention of `LIMIT`, as it never entered the symbol table.

Thus, you should prefer the use of

```
const int Limit = 10;
int data[Limit];
```

instead of

```
#define LIMIT 10
```

if you're given the opportunity (i.e. if you're in C++, and not in C).

And as mentioned, using an `std::vector` would be simpler and would remove the need for such constant expression.